# Mysql function remove words with less than 3 characters

Tags: mysql, string, function

I have a problem.

In my database i have certain stored procedures that perform a search on keywords i have. In my GUI (in asp.net) i have a function that takes care of my problem, but i need the same function in Mysql.

I need to strip a string from any words less than 3 characters and only keep the words that have more. So for instance, "hotels in amsterdam", would return "hotels amsterdam".

Edit: The fields are on innodb fulltext, for this reason i need to actually remove all words less than 3 becuase my stored procedure takes all " " and replaces it with " +". The FULLTEXT search is in boolean mode. I dont need to perform this on any row at all. I just need A function that strips a string from words that are less than 3 characters. The function will be used in a stored procedure and that stored procedure will then search on rows on the modified string value

My sql programming skills are not as good as in .Net and ive been searching for 2 days for a function that can do this for me without luck.

Im sorry but i dont even have any code so far to get things started, does anyone else have an idea on how to proceed or attack this problem? Since dynamic sql is not allowed in stored functions or triggers im completely stuck!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you don't need such functions at all? Maybe a fulltext index is what you're looking for? Short words like "in" are ignored there automatically.

Comment: How complex are the strings? If the words are always separated by spaces then it isn't too bad to do, but it you need to cope with  commas, full stops, etc, then it becomes more complex.

Comment: I have a fulltext index on it. Minimum word is 3. "in" is in the stoplist, but if i search on "+hotels +in +amsterdam" it doesnt show any result even though i have that exact keyword.

Comment: and of course, if remove the plus from the in then it displays the result. But for my solution i do need this function. String is simple, just spacaes that seperates the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that only spaces split the words, you can use something like the following:-

```
SELECT SomeId, GROUP_CONCAT(SomeWord ORDER BY aNum SEPARATOR " ")
FROM (SELECT SomeId, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(" ", SomeText, " "), " ", aNum), " ", -1) AS SomeWord, aNum, item_title_default
FROM SomeTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 + a.I + b.i * 10 + c.i * 100 AS aNum FROM integers a, integers b, integers c) SubInt
WHERE aNum <= (LENGTH(SomeText) - LENGTH(REPLACE(SomeText, " ", "")) + 2)
AND LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(" ", SomeText, " "), " ", aNum), " ", -1)) > 3
ORDER BY SomeId, aNum) Sub1
GROUP BY SomeId
```

This relies on a table of integers with a single column called i, with the rows with values 0 to 9. It copes with up to 1000 words but is easily extended.

EDIT - OK, here is a MySQL stored procedure to split the string up and remove any word 3 or less characters long. Again only splits on spaces.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION `func_Remove_ShortStrings`(InStr LONGTEXT) RETURNS LONGTEXT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE RetStr LONGTEXT DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE TempStr LONGTEXT DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE aWord LONGTEXT DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE WordLength INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET TempStr = TRIM(InStr);
    WHILE (LENGTH(TempStr) > 0) DO
        SET aWord = SUBSTRING_INDEX(TempStr, " ", 1);
        SET WordLength = LENGTH(aWord);
        IF (WordLength > 3) THEN
            SET RetStr = CONCAT(RetStr, " ", aWord);
        END IF;
        SET TempStr = TRIM(SUBSTRING(TempStr, WordLength + 1));
    END WHILE;

    return TRIM(RetStr);
END
```

Comment: Thanks but its not what im looking for, i need the function to take a string as parameter, and return a new string with the words less than 3 characters removed from the string. Im not sure how to convert this into that?

Comment: Are you doing this in advance for all rows, or on each row whenever a search is done? If in advance you could use something based on the above to populate an extra column. If you are doing it on each row on each search then I would expect performance to be very poor.

Comment: I dont need to perform this on any row at all. I just need A function that strips a string from words that are less than 3 characters. The function will be used in a stored procedure and that stored procedure will then search on rows on the modified string value

Comment: I have added a stored proc that will strip the words out. But I do think this will be very slow.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your excellent help and expertise! Im forever grateful!!! Thank you that was exactly what i needed!