# How do I get the names which are not the first and not last one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get the names which is not the first and not last one?

Example - Names:

```
Pablo Diego José Francisco
Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios
Daniel Mayes Matthew da Kitching 
Ben Wignall Elizabeth de Hann 
Emma Simpson Liam Wales Jacob
```

I'd like to have the results like below:

```
First_name  Middle_Name        Last_Name
----------------------------------------
Pablo       Diego José         Francisco
Juan        Nepomuceno María   Remedios
Daniel      Mayes Matthew      Kitching 
Ben         Wignall Elizabeth  Hann 
Emma        Simpson Liam Wales Jacob
```

For the middle name, the rules are: I want to get all the name after the first name and before the last name, but when happen of having small names like "de los" or "de" or "da", something like that, I wouldn't like to show it.

Comment: First you have to determine the criteria exactly what you don't want as a name only then you can figure out how to do it

Answer (score 3):

Here ONE possibility...

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  Name varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
  ('Pablo Diego José Francisco')
 ,('Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios')
 ,('Daniel Mayes Matthew da Kitching')
 ,('Ben Wignall Elizabeth de Hann')
 ,('Emma Simpson Liam Wales Jacob');


WITH cte AS(
  SELECT  Name, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(t.Name)),' de ', ' '), ' da ', ' '), ' los ', ' ') NameShort, REVERSE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(t.Name)),' de ', ' '), ' da ', ' '), ' los ', ' ')) NameShortRev
    FROM @t t
)
SELECT c.Name, c.NameShort
      ,LEFT(c.NameShort, CHARINDEX(' ', c.NameShort)) FirstName
      ,SUBSTRING(c.NameShort, CHARINDEX(' ', c.NameShort) + 1, LEN(c.NameShort) - CHARINDEX(' ', c.NameShortRev) - CHARINDEX(' ', c.NameShort)) MiddleName
      ,REVERSE(LEFT(c.NameShortRev, CHARINDEX(' ', c.NameShortRev))) LastName
  FROM cte c
```

Result:

```
Name                                    NameShort                       FirstName   MiddleName          LastName
Pablo Diego José Francisco              Pablo Diego José Francisco      Pablo       Diego José          Francisco
Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios   Juan Nepomuceno María Remedios  Juan        Nepomuceno María    Remedios
Daniel Mayes Matthew da Kitching        Daniel Mayes Matthew Kitching   Daniel      Mayes Matthew       Kitching
Ben Wignall Elizabeth de Hann           Ben Wignall Elizabeth Hann      Ben         Wignall Elizabeth   Hann
Emma Simpson Liam Wales Jacob           Emma Simpson Liam Wales Jacob   Emma        Simpson Liam Wales  Jacob
```

Comment: "i.e., there's no native way to do this"?

Comment: Check my answer @Blacksilver

Comment: I don't really know SQL so you're going to have to answer the question ;)

Comment: I extended the code a little to provide first and last name as well. No, no native way. You COULD rummage around in SQL Queries with XML and so on, but it is way oversized for your requirement and requires a little more understanding of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME TABLE ( NAME NVARCHAR(200) )

INSERT INTO @TABLE_NAME
VALUES ('Pablo Diego José Francisco'),
    ('Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios'),
    ('Daniel Mayes Matthew da Kitching'),
    ('Ben Wignall Elizabeth de Hann'),
    ('Emma Simpson Liam Wales Jacob')

SELECT  RTRIM(LEFT(NEW_NAME,START_POS)) AS First_name, 
        SUBSTRING(NEW_NAME,START_POS+1, LEN(NEW_NAME)-START_POS - END_POS ) AS Middle_Name ,
        LTRIM(RIGHT(NEW_NAME,END_POS)) AS Last_Name
FROM    (
    SELECT  NAME
            ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)),' de ', ' '), ' da ', ' '), ' los ', ' ') NEW_NAME
            ,CHARINDEX(' ',NAME) AS START_POS
            ,CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(NAME))  AS END_POS
    FROM    @TABLE_NAME
)   AS  T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CTE` and `LEFT()` , `RIGHT()`, `SUBSTRING()` functions:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('Pablo Diego José Francisco'),
('Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios'),
('Daniel Mayes Matthew da Kitching'), 
('Ben Wignall Elizabeth de Hann'),
('Emma Simpson Liam Wales Jacob');

With C as(
SELECT NAME,
       LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name, 1)) As First_name,
       RIGHT(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name), 1) ) As Last_Name
FROM @T)
    SELECT C.First_name,
           REPLACE(SUBSTRING(C.Name, LEN(C.First_name)+1,  LEN(C.Name)) , C.Last_Name, '') As Middle_Name, 
           C.Last_Name
    FROM C;
```

Result:

```
+------------+--------------------------+------------+
| First_name |       Middle_Name        | Last_Name  |
+------------+--------------------------+------------+
| Pablo      |  Diego José              |  Francisco |
| Juan       |  Nepomuceno María de los |  Remedios  |
| Daniel     |  Mayes Matthew da        |  Kitching  |
| Ben        |  Wignall Elizabeth de    |  Hann      |
| Emma       |  Simpson Liam Wales      |  Jacob     |
+------------+--------------------------+------------+
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/DKMG4403)**

Answer (score 0):

A longer answer here :)

First, we create a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143337/mysql-function-remove-words-with-less-than-3-characters) that removes words with 3 or less characters from given string (in our case will be Middle name).

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `func_Remove_ShortStrings`;
CREATE FUNCTION `func_Remove_ShortStrings`(InStr LONGTEXT) RETURNS LONGTEXT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN   
    DECLARE RetStr LONGTEXT DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE TempStr LONGTEXT DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE aWord LONGTEXT DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE WordLength INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET TempStr = TRIM(InStr);
    WHILE (LENGTH(TempStr) > 0) DO
        SET aWord = SUBSTRING_INDEX(TempStr, " ", 1);
        SET WordLength = LENGTH(aWord);
        IF (WordLength > 3) THEN
            SET RetStr = CONCAT(RetStr, " ", aWord);
        END IF;
        SET TempStr = TRIM(SUBSTRING(TempStr, WordLength + 1));
    END WHILE;

    return TRIM(RetStr);
END;
```

A way with **procedure** to get our names.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `splitNames`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `splitNames`(IN fullname varchar(150)) 
BEGIN       
    DECLARE First_name varchar(40);
    DECLARE Middle_Name varchar(60);
    DECLARE Last_Name varchar(50);

    SET First_name = LEFT(fullname,LOCATE(' ',fullname));
    SET Last_Name = RIGHT(fullname,LOCATE(' ',REVERSE(fullname)));
    SET Middle_Name = TRIM(LEADING First_name FROM fullname);
    SET Middle_Name = TRIM(TRAILING Last_Name FROM Middle_Name);
    SET Middle_Name = func_Remove_ShortStrings(Middle_Name);

    SELECT First_name, TRIM(Middle_Name) Middle_Name, TRIM(Last_Name) Last_Name;
END;

CALL splitNames("Ben Wignall Elizabeth de Hann");
```

Result:

```
First_name      Middle_Name         Last_Name
Ben             Wignall Elizabeth   Hann
```

---

**This is the way with functions**. Still needs the function to remove short words.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getFirstName;
CREATE FUNCTION getFirstName(fullname VARCHAR(150)) RETURNS varchar(50)
BEGIN
    RETURN LEFT(fullname,LOCATE(' ',fullname));
END;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getLastName;
CREATE FUNCTION getLastName(fullname VARCHAR(150)) RETURNS varchar(50)
BEGIN
    RETURN TRIM(RIGHT(fullname,LOCATE(' ',REVERSE(fullname))));
END;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getMiddleName;
CREATE FUNCTION getMiddleName(fullname VARCHAR(150)) RETURNS varchar(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE First_name varchar(40);
    DECLARE Middle_Name varchar(60);
    DECLARE Last_Name varchar(50);

    SET First_name = getFirstName(fullname);
    SET Last_Name = getLastName(fullname);
    SET Middle_Name = TRIM(LEADING First_name FROM fullname);
    SET Middle_Name = TRIM(TRAILING Last_Name FROM Middle_Name);
    RETURN func_Remove_ShortStrings(Middle_Name);
END;

SELECT getFirstName("Ben Wignall Elizabeth de Hann") firstName
, getMiddleName("Ben Wignall Elizabeth de Hann") middleName
, getLastName("Ben Wignall Elizabeth de Hann") lastName;
```